# Check if a specified type is a match for a generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0

Lets say I have the following dictionary:

```
protected Dictionary<Type, Type> MatchingTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
{
    { typeof(ObservableList<>), typeof(XmlDataModel.XmlObjectCollection<>) }
};
```

And I have a method with a signature that resembles this:

```
public CheckTypesMatch(Type one, Type two)
{
    return MatchingTypes.Any(kv => ((kv.Key == one && kv.Value == two) || (kv.Value == one && kv.Key == two)));
}
```

This will work fine for non-generic types, however for the generic types above this method will not return true.

Can someone outline how I can modify my code to make this method work for generic types?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CheckTypesMatch(typeof(ObservableList<>), typeof(XmlDataModel.XmlObjectCollection<>))
```

returns true for me.

If you want it to also return true for e.g. `typeof(ObervableList<int>)` you can rewrite it like the following:

```
public bool CheckTypesMatch(Type one, Type two)
{
    var one2 = one.IsGenericType ? one.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : one;
    var two2 = two.IsGenericType ? two.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : two;

    return MatchingTypes.Any(
        kv => ((kv.Key == one2 && kv.Value == two2) 
            || (kv.Value == one2 && kv.Key == two2)));
}
```